# Configuring MeterRegistry using environment variables

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes

How can I configure a meter registry using environment variables? My issue is that I need to set `management.statsd.metrics.export.host` in a spring boot app during deployment time. I know I could do it using code but I am trying to avoid code changes. -- Thanks

I can't find any reference to using environment variables and I am surprised since it is something very common on K8s environments.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Spring Boot documentation: [Binding From Environment Variables](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.relaxed-binding.environment-variables).

In your case the property `management.statsd.metrics.export.host` becomes `MANAGEMENT_STATSD_METRICS_EXPORT_HOST`.
Happy deployment!